# Chart.js don't show the first time

Tags: chart.js

I use chart.js to show a chart, ok, I put the data in datasets chart, it's ok, but I don't see the line the first time a see the chart. I explain:
The first picture is the first I see, when I call the component who have the code.
[image]
The second is what I see when I click over rectangle about leyend the hardcode dataset ("con medidas 2222) that I insert it like test.
[image]
The third is that I see when I click again over rectangle, so, that's would be the first. Why not?
[image]

I tried to add option hidden=false, and update the chart, but it doesn't works.
Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

I change to use ng2-chart ant it's works whith the same data downgrading chart.js to 2.9.4 version.